# Angular 4 - Pipe- Uncaught TypeError: t.sort is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

this error occurs in the vendor.js generated after the build, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**sort.pipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'sortBy'})
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array:Array<any>, args:string, args2:string):Array<string> {
        array = array || [];
        if (array !== undefined) {
            array.sort((a:any, b:any) => {
                if (args2) {
                    if (a[args][args2] < b[args][args2]) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (a[args][args2] > b[args][args2]) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (a[args] < b[args]) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (a[args] > b[args]) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

**product.filter.pipe.ts**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from "../service/product.services";

@Pipe({name: 'productFilter'})
export class ProductFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(products:Product[], text:string):Product[] {

        if (products == null || text == null || text.length == 0) {
            return products;
        }

        return products.filter(product => {
            return product.id.toString().indexOf(text) >= 0 ||
                product.name.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        })

    }
}
```

**Modules**

```
import { ClientFilterPipe } from './shared/pipe/client-filter.pipe';
import { OrderFilterPipe } from './shared/pipe/order-filter.pipe';
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {ChartsModule} from "ng2-charts/ng2-charts";
import {OrderComponent} from "./order/order.component";
import {DashboardRoutingModule} from "./dashboard-routing.module";
import {ClientComponent} from "./client/client.component";
import {ProductComponent} from "./product/product.component";
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';
import {OrderService} from './shared/service/order.service'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
import {ProductFilterPipe} from "./shared/pipe/product-filter.pipe";
import {SortByPipe} from "./shared/pipe/sort.pipe";
import { SharedModule } from "app/shared/shared.module";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        DashboardRoutingModule,
        ChartsModule,
        TextMaskModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        OrderComponent,
        ClientComponent,
        ProductComponent,
        ProductFilterPipe,
        OrderFilterPipe,
        ClientFilterPipe,
        SortByPipe
    ],
    providers: [
        OrderService
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule {
}
```

**html tag**

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of (AllProducts | productFilter:textSearch | sortBy:ordination)">
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.9",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.9",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.0",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.4.0",
    "ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "7.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.2.1"
  }
```

**ERRO**

> Uncaught TypeError: t.sort is not a function
>       at t.transform (1.c084fff4f7c75c6a444a.chunk.js:formatted:266)
>       at vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1
>       at proxyViewClass.View_t0.detectChangesInternal (VM3772 component.ngfactory.js:1815)
>       at proxyViewClass.t.detectChanges (vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1)
>       at proxyViewClass.t.internalDetectChanges (vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1)
>       at proxyViewClass.View_t_Host0.detectChangesInternal (VM3775 host.ngfactory.js:33)
>       at proxyViewClass.t.detectChanges (vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.detectChangesInNestedViews (vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1)
>       at proxyViewClass.View_e0.detectChangesInternal (VM3721 component.ngfactory.js:199)
>       at proxyViewClass.t.detectChanges (vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1)
>       at proxyViewClass.t.internalDetectChanges (vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1)
>       at proxyViewClass.View_e_Host0.detectChangesInternal (VM3723 host.ngfactory.js:27)
>       at proxyViewClass.t.detectChanges (vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.detectChangesInNestedViews (vendor.d076f160cfb2a88c98b2.bundle.js:1)
>       at proxyViewClass.View_anonymous_00.detectChangesInternal (/anonymous_1/anonymous_0/component.ngfactory.js:27)

Comment: the project path: https://github.com/rogeriob2br/pizza_planet/tree/pizza_planet

Comment: tried project at my end worked fine

Comment: you dont need this line  `array = array || [];` just do `if(array)`, there is seems to be issue with array data , i tried with static data at my end and there no error

Comment: thanks Panay, but in developer mode running with ]out error, in production mode have this problem. I run the production mode with "ng build --prod --aot=false,  end expose the dist folder with http-server dist/. This error occurs in chrome console.

Comment: this error occurs if you enter in  products page,